# Is there a way to build projects or solutions by right clicking them in explorer?

Tags: msbuild, explorer

Occasionally, I find myself opening solutions in visual studio just to build them. I was considering creating a shell extension (purely for convenience) that would run msbuild on the solution for me without opening Visual Studio, but I was wondering if something like that already existed.

Does anyone know of a tool that allows you to build projects from an explorer context menu?

Comment: The issue is framework_version.  Sometimes you build with v4.0 or v4.5.  Which is why I write a mini .bat file (3-4 lines) that does what you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the command to do so or generate a BAT file that takes the solution file as an argument you can create a registry entry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Compile solution...\command.  You might be able to even use the .__sln entry in there somehow.